How to use resumeHandle in NetWkstaUserEnum
This code has been taken from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/lmwksta/nf-lmwksta-netwkstauserenum
I just modified dwPrefMaxLen to 100 to simulate the case where it returns just one user.
In real case I put 4096 in my application, I didn't put MAX_PREFERRED_LENGTH, because I don't want risk to allocate too much memory/ block the application because the call can retrieve too many users.
In this case as I understand from documentation, the call should just return ERROR_MORE_DATA and we can recall it with resumeHandle to get the remaining users.
But this is not working, the call seems to completely ignore the resumeHandle and retrieve always the same list with the result to stay stuck in the loop forever.
What Am I doing wrong? is it a windows bug?
#ifndef UNICODE
#define UNICODE
#endif
#pragma comment(lib, "netapi32.lib")

#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <windows.h> 
#include <lm.h>

int wmain(int argc, wchar_t *argv[])
{
   LPWKSTA_USER_INFO_0 pBuf = NULL;
   LPWKSTA_USER_INFO_0 pTmpBuf;
   DWORD dwLevel = 0;
   DWORD dwPrefMaxLen = 100;
   DWORD dwEntriesRead = 0;
   DWORD dwTotalEntries = 0;
   DWORD dwResumeHandle = 0;
   DWORD i;
   DWORD dwTotalCount = 0;
   NET_API_STATUS nStatus;
   LPWSTR pszServerName = NULL;

   if (argc > 2)
   {
      fwprintf(stderr, L"Usage: %s [\\\\ServerName]\n", argv[0]);
      exit(1);
   }
   // The server is not the default local computer.
   //
   if (argc == 2)
      pszServerName = argv[1];
   fwprintf(stderr, L"\nUsers currently logged on %s:\n", pszServerName);
   //
   // Call the NetWkstaUserEnum function, specifying level 0.
   //
   do // begin do
   {
      nStatus = NetWkstaUserEnum( pszServerName,
                                  dwLevel,
                                  (LPBYTE*)&pBuf,
                                  dwPrefMaxLen,
                                  &dwEntriesRead,
                                  &dwTotalEntries,
                                  &dwResumeHandle);
      //
      // If the call succeeds,
      //
      if ((nStatus == NERR_Success) || (nStatus == ERROR_MORE_DATA))
      {
         if ((pTmpBuf = pBuf) != NULL)
         {
            //
            // Loop through the entries.
            //
            for (i = 0; (i < dwEntriesRead); i++)
            {
               assert(pTmpBuf != NULL);

               if (pTmpBuf == NULL)
               {
                  //
                  // Only members of the Administrators local group
                  //  can successfully execute NetWkstaUserEnum
                  //  locally and on a remote server.
                  //
                  fprintf(stderr, "An access violation has occurred\n");
                  break;
               }
               //
               // Print the user logged on to the workstation. 
               //
               wprintf(L"\t-- %s\n", pTmpBuf->wkui0_username);

               pTmpBuf++;
               dwTotalCount++;
            }
         }
      }
      //
      // Otherwise, indicate a system error.
      //
      else
         fprintf(stderr, "A system error has occurred: %d\n", nStatus);
      //
      // Free the allocated memory.
      //
      if (pBuf != NULL)
      {
         NetApiBufferFree(pBuf);
         pBuf = NULL;
      }
   }
   // 
   // Continue to call NetWkstaUserEnum while 
   //  there are more entries. 
   // 
   while (nStatus == ERROR_MORE_DATA); // end do
   //
   // Check again for allocated memory.
   //
   if (pBuf != NULL)
      NetApiBufferFree(pBuf);
   //
   // Print the final count of workstation users.
   //
   fprintf(stderr, "\nTotal of %d entries enumerated\n", dwTotalCount);

   return 0;
}


There's no C++ specific functionality in the sample code. If you're readind MS docs, remember that they have a wrong C++ tag. Win32 API is pure C, and CLR is MS extension. There's zero bit of C++ to be found in MS documents. You'd better remove the C++ tag.

From the documentation, a return code of ERROR_MORE_DATA indicates that the buffer is not large enough. If you keep calling the function without increasing the buffer size then it's going to keep returning ERROR_MORE_DATA. You either need to increase the buffer size or just pass MAX_PREFERRED_LENGTH. The provided sample code is rather poor, as is unfortunately often the case.

@Luke so what is the purpose of dwResumeHandle? from the documentation I expect that I set a buffer big enough to hold 100 users, for example dwPrefMaxLen=65536, and I have 10000 users, I can continue the iteration with dwResumeHandle.

if ERROR_MORE_DATA means buffer not large enough, then the loop with dwResumeHandle has no absolute sense

@StefanoBalzarotti The usage of dwResumeHandle and dwPrefMaxLen are completely unrelated.  dwResumeHandle is used as an index for the enumeration. dwPrefMaxLen is used to control the size of the buffer. If the buffer is too small, return value is ERROR_MORE_DATA; if the buffer is large enough, return value is ERROR_SUCCESS. You determine whether or not to continue based on whether or not dwEntriesRead is zero.

@Luke, this doesn't look the case from Microsoft documentation, they are checking if ((nStatus == NERR_Success) || (nStatus == ERROR_MORE_DATA)) and not if entriesread < totalentries

@Luke if what you are saying is correct it means also that entriesread is not the number returned by NetWkstaUserEnum, but the index of the last element enumerated. this would also imply that the loop in the example for (i = 0; (i < dwEntriesRead); i++) is wrong

Ah, looks like ERROR_MORE_DATA is used to indicate two conditions: 1) at least one entry was enumerated and there are more entries to enumerate or 2) the buffer is too small to contain even a single entry. I guess you could differentiate which condition based on whether or not dwEntriesRead is 0. Nope, I think this API is just irrevocably broken if you don't use MAX_PREFERRED_LENGTH.

when we call NetWkstaUserEnum it do request over \\servername\Pipe\wkssvc pipe to LanmanWorkstation service. from server side request handled in wkssvc.dll in function NetrWkstaUserEnum
this api call LsaCallAuthenticationPackage with MsV1_0EnumerateUsers on MSV1_0_PACKAGE_NAME and then MsV1_0GetUserInfo for every LogonId.
most job is done inside WsEnumUserInfo function. despite this yet, 2003 src code, i look this under latest win 11 and code was not changes since.

if we need this from local machine, we can direct call MsV1_0EnumerateUsers  and MsV1_0GetUserInfo. but we need have TCB privileges for this. but if we run as admin, we can got it. code can look like:
NTSTATUS status, ProtocolStatus;
HANDLE LsaHandle;
ImpersonateToken(&tp_Tcb);// not listed here
status = LsaConnectUntrusted(&LsaHandle);
RevertToSelf();
if (0 <= status)
{
    ULONG AuthenticationPackage;
    LSA_STRING PackageName;
    RtlInitString(&PackageName, MSV1_0_PACKAGE_NAME);
    if (0 <= (status = LsaLookupAuthenticationPackage(LsaHandle, &PackageName, &AuthenticationPackage)))
    {
        MSV1_0_ENUMUSERS_REQUEST request = { MsV1_0EnumerateUsers };
        PMSV1_0_ENUMUSERS_RESPONSE response = 0;
        ULONG len;
        if (0 <= (status = LsaCallAuthenticationPackage(LsaHandle, AuthenticationPackage, &request, sizeof(request),
            (void**)&response, &len, &ProtocolStatus)))
        {
            if (0 > ProtocolStatus)
            {
                status = ProtocolStatus;
            }
            else if (ULONG NumberOfLoggedOnUsers = response->NumberOfLoggedOnUsers)
            {
                PLUID LogonIds = response->LogonIds;
                PULONG EnumHandles = response->EnumHandles; // InterlockedIncrement(&NlpEnumerationHandle);
                MSV1_0_GETUSERINFO_REQUEST getuser = { MsV1_0GetUserInfo };
                do 
                {
                    ULONG EnumHandle = *EnumHandles++;
                    getuser.LogonId = *LogonIds++;
                    PMSV1_0_GETUSERINFO_RESPONSE userinfo = 0;

                    if (0 <= (status = LsaCallAuthenticationPackage(LsaHandle, 
                        AuthenticationPackage, &getuser, sizeof(getuser),
                        (void**)&userinfo, &len, &ProtocolStatus)))
                    {
                        if (0 > ProtocolStatus)
                        {
                            status = ProtocolStatus;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            WCHAR wz[SECURITY_MAX_SID_STRING_CHARACTERS];
                            UNICODE_STRING us = { 0, sizeof(wz), wz };
                            RtlConvertSidToUnicodeString(&us, userinfo->UserSid, FALSE);
                            DbgPrint("%x:{%08x-%08x}: %x %wZ\\%wZ %wZ \"%wZ\"\n", 
                                EnumHandle, // some uniqie number
                                getuser.LogonId.HighPart, getuser.LogonId.LowPart,
                                userinfo->LogonType, 
                                &userinfo->LogonDomainName,
                                &userinfo->UserName,
                                &us,
                                &userinfo->LogonServer);
                        }

                        LsaFreeReturnBuffer(userinfo);
                    }

                } while (--NumberOfLoggedOnUsers);
            }
            LsaFreeReturnBuffer(response);
        }
    }

    LsaDeregisterLogonProcess(LsaHandle);
}

structures defined in ntifs.h from wdk. if you have problems to include it, we can simply copy paste it from there
//
// MsV1_0EnumerateUsers submit buffer and response
//

typedef struct _MSV1_0_ENUMUSERS_REQUEST {
    MSV1_0_PROTOCOL_MESSAGE_TYPE MessageType;
} MSV1_0_ENUMUSERS_REQUEST, *PMSV1_0_ENUMUSERS_REQUEST;

typedef struct _MSV1_0_ENUMUSERS_RESPONSE {
    MSV1_0_PROTOCOL_MESSAGE_TYPE MessageType;
    ULONG NumberOfLoggedOnUsers;
    PLUID LogonIds;
    PULONG EnumHandles;
} MSV1_0_ENUMUSERS_RESPONSE, *PMSV1_0_ENUMUSERS_RESPONSE;

//
// MsV1_0GetUserInfo submit buffer and response
//

typedef struct _MSV1_0_GETUSERINFO_REQUEST {
    MSV1_0_PROTOCOL_MESSAGE_TYPE MessageType;
    LUID LogonId;
} MSV1_0_GETUSERINFO_REQUEST, *PMSV1_0_GETUSERINFO_REQUEST;

typedef struct _MSV1_0_GETUSERINFO_RESPONSE {
    MSV1_0_PROTOCOL_MESSAGE_TYPE MessageType;
    PSID UserSid;
    UNICODE_STRING UserName;
    UNICODE_STRING LogonDomainName;
    UNICODE_STRING LogonServer;
    SECURITY_LOGON_TYPE LogonType;
} MSV1_0_GETUSERINFO_RESPONSE, *PMSV1_0_GETUSERINFO_RESPONSE;

internally msv1_0 have linked list ( with NlpActiveLogonListAnchor head) of private ACTIVE_LOGON structures ( used to keep track of all private information related to a particular LogonId.). this struct have
ULONG EnumHandle;           // The enumeration handle of this logon session

member, assigned in next way:
//
// Get the next enumeration handle for this session.
//

pActiveLogonEntry->EnumHandle = (ULONG)InterlockedIncrement((PLONG)&NlpEnumerationHandle);

msv1_0 enumerate list from last to first entry. by Flink links. as results
MSV1_0_ENUMUSERS_RESPONSE::EnumHandles go in descending order
//
// Loop through the Active Logon Table copying the EnumHandle of
//  each session.
//

pEnumResponse->EnumHandles = (PULONG)(ClientBufferDesc.UserBuffer +
                                (pWhere - ClientBufferDesc.MsvBuffer));
for ( pScan = NlpActiveLogonListAnchor.Flink;
     pScan != &NlpActiveLogonListAnchor;
     pScan = pScan->Flink )

https://github.com/wisny101/Windows-Server-2003-Source/blob/master/ds/security/protocols/msv_sspi/nlmain.c#L1983
but WsEnumUserInfo assume that it go in ascending order
https://github.com/wisny101/Windows-Server-2003-Source/blob/master/ds/netapi/svcdlls/wkssvc/server/user.c#L622
if (StartEnumeration <= EnumUsersResponse->EnumHandles[i]) {

and
//
// Get the enumeration starting point.
//
if (ARGUMENT_PRESENT(ResumeHandle)) {
    StartEnumeration = *ResumeHandle;
}

and
if (status == ERROR_MORE_DATA && ARGUMENT_PRESENT(ResumeHandle)) {
    *ResumeHandle = EnumUsersResponse->EnumHandles[i - 1];
}

let we have m = NumberOfLoggedOnUsers with next EnumHandles, go in ascending order
N(0) < .. < N(i-1) < N(i)  < .. < N(m-1)

MsV1_0GetUserInfo return it in in descending order
N(m-1), .. , N(i), N(i-1), .., N(0)

let only N(m-1), .. , N(i) fit to prefmaxlen
so NetWkstaUserEnum return (m - i) entries and ResumeHandle = i - 1
(loop is breaked on copy N(i-1) entry with WsPackageUserInfo return ERROR_MORE_DATA )
so on next call to NetWkstaUserEnum with ResumeHandle == i - 1
will be enumerated only entries with N >= N(i-1)
so again N(m-1), .. , N(i) and may be N(i-1) if you increase buffer

also you can do next simply demo test - call NetWkstaUserEnum several times, with different buffer sizes, but not big enough to accommodate all users, and with dwResumeHandle = 0 as input parameter - the bigger the buffer size - the bigger the dwEntriesRead will be when returning and the less the dwResumeHandle value will be
void eu()
{
    ULONG dwEntriesRead, dwTotalEntries, prefmaxlen = 0x10, dwResumeHandle;

    NET_API_STATUS nStatus;
    do 
    {
        PWKSTA_USER_INFO_0 pBuf;

        switch (nStatus = NetWkstaUserEnum(0, 0, (PBYTE*)&pBuf, 
            prefmaxlen, &dwEntriesRead, 
            &dwTotalEntries, &(dwResumeHandle = 0)))
        {
        case ERROR_MORE_DATA:
        case NERR_Success:
            DbgPrint("(%x)=%u dwEntriesRead=%u dwResumeHandle=%u\n", 
                prefmaxlen, nStatus, dwEntriesRead, dwResumeHandle);
            if (dwEntriesRead)
            {
                pBuf += dwEntriesRead;
                do 
                {
                    DbgPrint("\t-- %ws\n", (--pBuf)->wkui0_username);
                } while (--dwEntriesRead);
            }
            prefmaxlen += 0x10;
            NetApiBufferFree(pBuf);
            break;
        }

    } while (ERROR_MORE_DATA == nStatus);
}

and output
(10)=234 dwEntriesRead=0 dwResumeHandle=5
(20)=234 dwEntriesRead=0 dwResumeHandle=5
(30)=234 dwEntriesRead=1 dwResumeHandle=2
    -- Administrator
(40)=234 dwEntriesRead=2 dwResumeHandle=1
    -- User
    -- Administrator
(50)=0 dwEntriesRead=3 dwResumeHandle=0
    -- User
    -- User
    -- Administrator

and if direct run first code snipet, result will be
5:{00000000-00483cba}: 2 DESKTOP-*******\Administrator S-1-5-21-... "DESKTOP-*******"
2:{00000000-000341ef}: 2 DESKTOP-*******\User S-1-5-21-... "DESKTOP-*******"
1:{00000000-00034188}: 2 DESKTOP-*******\User S-1-5-21-... "DESKTOP-*******"


Wow, that is a really silly bug. If it's been like this for the past 20 years I guess there must not be many people who use the API like this.

yes, not changed frpm 2003 up to latest win 11

I think it will stay there for other 20 years, if Microsoft doesn't provide a way to report bugs: https://github.com/microsoft/WindowsAppSDK/issues/4955

I think this API is impossible to use "correctly" without specifying MAX_PREFERRED_LENGTH (or at least a "sufficiently large" buffer).
int main()
{
    DWORD MaxLength = 64;
    DWORD Iteration = 0;
    DWORD ResumeHandle = 0;
    for (;;)
    {
        LPWKSTA_USER_INFO_1 Buffer = NULL;
        DWORD EntriesRead = 0;
        DWORD TotalEntries = 0;
        printf("Iteration=%u\n", Iteration);
        printf("    <Input>\n");
        printf("    MaxLength=%u\n", MaxLength);
        printf("    ResumeHandle=%u\n", ResumeHandle);
        NET_API_STATUS Status = NetWkstaUserEnum(NULL, 1, (LPBYTE*)&Buffer, MaxLength, &EntriesRead, &TotalEntries, &ResumeHandle);
        printf("    <Output>\n");
        printf("    Status=%u\n", Status);
        printf("    EntriesRead=%u\n", EntriesRead);
        printf("    TotalEntries=%u\n", TotalEntries);
        printf("    ResumeHandle=%u\n", ResumeHandle);
        if (EntriesRead)
        {
            for (DWORD Index = 0; Index < EntriesRead; Index++)
            {
                LPWKSTA_USER_INFO_1 User = Buffer + Index;
                printf("    Username: %ls\n", User->wkui1_username);
                printf("    LogonDomain: %ls\n", User->wkui1_logon_domain);
                printf("    OtherDomains: %ls\n", User->wkui1_oth_domains);
                printf("    LogonServer: %ls\n", User->wkui1_logon_server);
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
        if (Status == ERROR_MORE_DATA)
        {
            NetApiBufferFree(Buffer);
            Buffer = NULL;
            MaxLength *= 2;
        }
        else if (Status == ERROR_SUCCESS)
        {
            break;
        }
        Iteration++;
    }
    return 0;
}

With MaxLength initialized to 64, I get the following output:
Iteration=0
    <Input>
    MaxLength=64
    ResumeHandle=0
    <Output>
    Status=234
    EntriesRead=0
    TotalEntries=2
    ResumeHandle=2

Iteration=1
    <Input>
    MaxLength=128
    ResumeHandle=2
    <Output>
    Status=0
    EntriesRead=1
    TotalEntries=1
    ResumeHandle=2
    Username: lukexxxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com
    LogonDomain: MicrosoftAccount
    OtherDomains:
    LogonServer:

With MaxLength initialized to 128, I get the following output:
Iteration=0
    <Input>
    MaxLength=128
    ResumeHandle=0
    <Output>
    Status=234
    EntriesRead=1
    TotalEntries=2
    ResumeHandle=1
    Username: lukexxxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com
    LogonDomain: MicrosoftAccount
    OtherDomains:
    LogonServer:

Iteration=1
    <Input>
    MaxLength=256
    ResumeHandle=1
    <Output>
    Status=0
    EntriesRead=2
    TotalEntries=2
    ResumeHandle=1
    Username: lukexxxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com
    LogonDomain: MicrosoftAccount
    OtherDomains:
    LogonServer:
    Username: lukexxxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com
    LogonDomain: MicrosoftAccount
    OtherDomains:
    LogonServer:

With MaxLength initialized to MAX_PREFERRED_LENGTH, I get the following output:
Iteration=0
    <Input>
    MaxLength=4294967295
    ResumeHandle=0
    <Output>
    Status=0
    EntriesRead=2
    TotalEntries=2
    ResumeHandle=0
    Username: lukexxxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com
    LogonDomain: MicrosoftAccount
    OtherDomains:
    LogonServer:
    Username: lukexxxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com
    LogonDomain: MicrosoftAccount
    OtherDomains:
    LogonServer:

I have no idea why there is a discrepancy between the first case (64) and the latter cases (128 and MAX_PREFERRED_LENGTH). I'd be very curious for someone to give this a try on a server with many users logged in.

you have 2 users with EnumHandles = 1 and 2
internal api return users in next order [2, 1]
and it return users with EnumHandles >= ResumeHandle .
so with ResumeHandle=2 it return only U2 but never U1 .
with ResumeHandle=1 it already can return all users..
internal implementation assume [1, 2] user order, but it is [2,1]

note - with increasing buffer - ResumeHandle is decreases on return

According to the Doc:Network Management Function Buffer Lengths

Applications that specify buffer sizes when calling network management
enumeration functions (and various data retrieval functions) must
specify buffers large enough to hold the returned information
structure (or structures) plus the strings to which their members
point. If you do not specify a large enough buffer to receive all the
available entries, the function returns ERROR_MORE_DATA. Enumeration
calls do not return partial entries.

I suggest you should use MAX_PREFERRED_LENGTH.
If you specify another value in the prefmaxlen parameter, the buffer size is not large enough to accommodate all the entries, and when the function returns ERROR_MORE_DATA, you need to increase the buffer size by yourself.
If you specify the value MAX_PREFERRED_LENGTH in the prefmaxlen parameter, the network management functions allocate the amount of memory required for the data.

So what is the purpose of dwResumeHandle?
what if there are 10000 users and I specify MAX_PREFERRED_LENGTH? would you mean that there is no way to do an incremental fetch because that call needs to allocate the memory to hold all 10000 users?

@StefanoBalzarotti 10000 user currently logged on to the workstation ?

@RbMm this function retrieves also batch and services users, not sure if 10000 can happen, but we had a customer with hundreds of users logged. the call was very slow and we decided to limit the buffer and fetch them asynchronously with a timeout. unfortunately this doesn't work.  even if you pass resumeHandle this function fetch always the same set of users in an infinite loop.

The resumehandle should be zero on the first call. This indicates that you're starting the enumeration from the beginning.
if the function returns ERROR_MORE_DATA, it means that the buffer size is insufficient to hold all entries and not be able to enumerate all the data at once. NetWkstaUserEnum will set resumeHandle to a value that you can use in subsequent calls to continue the enumeration.
And then you could continue to enumerate the data using the resumeHandle value from the previous call.
resumeHandle is not used to do an incremental fetch.

@StefanoBalzarotti are dwEntriesRead was != 0 ? and you do this for remote machine ( ie pszServerName not 0) ?

no I am doing it on a local machine, pszServerName = 0.
I did a test on a machine with dwPrefMaxLen = 4096. dwEntriesRead is initialized to 0, and the api sets it to 16, dwTotalEntries initialized to 0 and set to 39 by the api.
dwResumeHandle initialized to 0, then set by the api to another number, then passed with the new value but ignored.

@StefanoBalzarotti if you doing it on a local machine simply use MsV1_0EnumerateUsers . i sure that NetWkstaUserEnum have bug in implementation

you mean  LsaCallAuthenticationPackage with  MsV1_0EnumerateUsers, I'll check it it thank you. for NetWkstaUserEnum I think too, but I am waiting some confirmations before reporting the bug to microsoft.

@StefanoBalzarotti, yes, exactly - LsaCallAuthenticationPackage with MsV1_0EnumerateUsers and got MSV1_0_ENUMUSERS_RESPONSE

This is not a bug, this is just a very silly API choice. There is no reason to ever set dwPrefMaxLen to anything other than MAX_PREFERRED_LENGTH.  If there are 10000  users this function is not going to allocate a buffer large enough to hold all of them; it's going to split it out into chunks and you'll have to loop multiple times to enumerate all the users.

Well, after actually trying to write code to use this API I think that either it is impossible to use correctly without specifying MAX_PREFERRED_LENGTH or there is indeed a bug with it.

@Luke no, the api contain bug exactly in implementation
